# Вытащить в js значение поля через запрос к API приложения

Tags: php, javascript, json

При авторизации пользователя на сайте создаётся его уникальный токен. Задача - подставить этот токен на странице *.php в переменную js из API приложения авторизации, где токен записывается в поле Xssidentifier.

Пробовала использовать конструкции вида

```
var okCustomerToken = '<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['Xssidentifier']) ? $_SESSION['Xssidentifier'] : '0'); ?>'
```

Не помогло. Хотя другие данные из этого же приложения таким образом спокойно вытаскиваются.

Из документации известны параметры запроса:

method  - getprofile2

token   - токен, полученный приложением для доступа к API

format  - формат ответа (xml, json)

appid   - идентификатор приложения

fields  - список названия полей через запятую (в данном случае нужен только Xssidentifier)

sig = sign(appid,format,method,token,fields) - подпись запроса

Помогите, пожалуйста, сформировать правильный запрос.

P.S. Я не программист, я только учусь. Учусь на практике и своим ходом. Прошу прощения, если вопрос слишком примитивен.

Comment: `session_start();` присутствует на странице ?

Comment: Нет, не присутствует

Comment: Включен, в страницу из другого файла?

Comment: О, нашла session_start.